# why is it finding the file but then it says its not there?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, loops

I am trying to print out the content of an excel file I have in a folder named 'Teacher Sheets'. The file is named "12.xlsx" . I run a loop to check if the file is in there and it finds it. You can tell because it runs what's inside the loop. But then when I try to print out its contents, it says the file is not found. What's wrong with the code?

[image]

Comment: Can you try adding r"" in the path, pass the filepath as a raw string.
r"C:/Users ... ..."

Comment: `dataframe = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, file))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the filepath as a raw string; `r"C:/Users/ .. /.. /.. "`